# jq: error: Could not open file config_block.json

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was trying to Add an Org to an existing Channel, by referring: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update.html

Successfully fetched the most recent block, using the command:

```
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

Next, tutorial guides to execute the following:

```
configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config config_block.json > config.json
```

I ran into the following error:

```
jq: error: Could not open file config_block.json: No such file or directory
configtxlator: error: expected command but got "proto_decode", try --help
```

It seems I need to first generate `config_block.json`, but how?

Answer (score 2):

Actuallay real problem is:

> "configtxlator: error: expected command but got "proto_decode", try
>   --help"

Also we faced same problem and solved using configtxlator restapi.
You can do same task on cli, step by step:

```
configtxlator start & #to start rest api
```

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @config_block.pb http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/decode/common.Block > config_block.json
```

```
jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config config_block.json > config.json
```

Comment: If you are following tutorial on 

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_update.html


also may be this link 

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html

could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The version of  Docker images and corresponding utilities is not right. "Add an Org to an existing Channel" needs the version “1.1.0-preview”.

The version of the doc that you read is latest, so your Docker images and corresponding utilities need the version “1.1.0-preview”.

The version of the doc that you read is "v1.1.0-alpha", so your Docker images and corresponding utilities need the version “v1.1.0-alpha”.

Answer (score 1):

After v1.1.0-rc1 release, I followed the updated instructions, and able to execute all the commands of "Adding an Org to a Channel" successfully.

The updated command is as follows:

```
configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json
```

which is actually just omitting `config_block.json` from the previous command.